# Determine the value of b and c such that the function is continuous

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

Determine the value of b and c such that the function is continuous on the entire real number line.

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}x+1 ,& 1<x<3\\
        x^2+bx+c, &|x-2|\ge 1\end{cases}$$

May I know how to get the value of b and c?

Comment: What does $x^2+bx+c$ equal when $x=1$? When $x=3$?

Comment: Hi John , I just wondering the part of |x-2| >=1 and it makes me feel confuse.

Comment: Absolute values confuse me sometimes too (e.g.$ \mid x-1\mid + \mid x+2\mid + \mid x+5\mid$). In this example though ($\mid x-2\mid \ge 1$), try to break it up into cases. When $x\lt 2$, for what values of $x$ is $\mid x-2\mid \ge 1$? When $x\gt 2$, for what values of $x$ is $\mid x-2\mid \ge 1$?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to get two equations so that you derive $a$ and $b$. Which equations you should try to get follows from the continuity condition. Since if $f(x)$ needs to be continuous we need that $$
x+1=x^2+bx+c
$$
for $x\in\{1,3\}$

Extra:

> for $x=1$ we get $1=c+b$ and for $x=3$ we get $-5=3b+c$
>  this gives us that $b=-3$ and so $c=4$

Comment: When $x = 1$, you should have $\color{red}{1} = b + c$.

Comment: Yes that is true. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

For it to be continuous the limit when x approaches 1 and when x approaches 3 must exist and have a finite value in both cases. This is equivalent to solve the following equations:

$$ 2 = 1+b+c \qquad (x=1)$$
$$4 = 9 + 3b + c \qquad (x=3)$$

This gives you the solution $b=-3$ and $c=4$